# get post data in a php page called by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have called the page **search.php** from ajax:

```
function search(){


                  var title=$("#search").val();

                  if(title!=""){

                     $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"search.php",
                        data:"title="+title+"&idTratta="+<?php echo $idTratta ?>,
                        success:function(data){
                            $("#result").html(data);
                            $("#search").val("");
                         }
                      });
                  }



             }
```

Now in **search.php** I get the result of a query in a html table and I created radio buttons in a form that when each form is submitted I get the value of the radio button's clicked and update a row in the db:

```
$title = $_POST["title"];
$idTratta = $_POST["idTratta"];

$SimpleUsers = new SimpleUsers();
$users = $SimpleUsers -> searchUser($title, $idTratta);

foreach ($users as $user) :
    echo "<tr>
                    <td>" . $user["nome"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $user["role"] . "</td>
                    <td class='right'><form action='' method='post'><label>
    <input type='radio' name=" . $user["nome"] . " id='c'  value='1' ";
    if ($user["role"] == 'configuratore')
        echo "checked='checked'  />C</label>";
    else
        echo "/>C</label>";
    echo "<label>
    <input type='radio' name=" . $user["nome"] . " id='va' value='2' ";
    if ($user["role"] == 'visualizzatore avanzato')
        echo "checked='checked'  />VA</label>";
    else
        echo "/>VA</label>";
    echo "<label>
    <input type='radio' name=" . $user["nome"] . " id='v' value='3' ";
    if ($user["role"] == 'visualizzatore')
        echo "checked='checked' />V </label>";
    else
        echo "/>V </label>";
    echo "<input type= 'submit' name='sub_" . $user["nome"] . "'value='Cambia'/></form></td>
                </tr>";

    $sub = 'sub_';

    if ($_POST[$sub . '' . $user["nome"]]) {

        $permission = $_POST[$user["nome"]];
        $SimpleUsers -> updateUserPermission($user["nome"], $idTratta, $permission);

    }
endforeach;
```

The problem is that in **search.php** I am unable to catch POST variables, how I can get it?

**EDIT**
This is the piece of code which doesn't work:

```
if ($_POST[$sub . '' . $user["nome"]]) {

    $permission = $_POST[$user["nome"]];
    $SimpleUsers -> updateUserPermission($user["nome"], $idTratta, $permission);

}
```

Comment: What does show `$_POST ` in search.php? Have you tried with `print_r($_POST)`?

Answer (score 0):

The data shouldn't be parsed as text but instead as an js array like this:

```
data: {title: title, idTratta : <?php echo $idTratta ?>},
```

EDIT:

A example for sending the form data would be:

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());
formData['idTratta'] = <?php echo $idTratta ?>;
$.ajax({
     type:"post",
     url:"search.php",
     data:formData,
     success:function(data){
       $("#result").html(data);
       $("#search").val("");
    }
});
```

And than using json_decode in your php form to turn it into a PHP array again. Its kind of dirty but it should work

Comment: ok, thank you, i edited it, but for my problem there is a solution?

Comment: @rivas202 what problem? You still not getting nothing on $_POST? Or you can now read data from $_POST after sending data as {title: title, idTratta : <?php echo $idTratta ?>} in your ajax call?

Comment: I make a test and I see that the post vaiables are send but the problem is that I need to refresh two times the page to see the upadate of radio button

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the correct one than? Changing the radio button isn't the question. $("#radio_1").prop("checked", true) < this should do the trick, just change the id to the one off the radio button you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
$.post("`search.php`", { title : title , idTratta : '<?php echo $idTratta ?>'}, 
function (data) {
    $("`#result`").html(data);
    $("`#search`").val("");
});
```